# 'self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES' Not Working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I know my question is duplicated but please help me all the same question did not help me.

I have a scrollView in paging mode and in its table view when click in any cell of table view I would like for the details view to appear

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 NSLog(@"ok");
Details *details=[[Details alloc]initWithNibName:@"Details" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];  
}
```

The Details view does not appear; Nothing happens

I put NSLog to know if there is error in click event cell

Note : I set the UINavigatiorController in AppDelegate

Comment: are you setting it as the root view controller? what kind of app is it?

Comment: Is the "OK" log message reached? Is this view controller in a navigation controller? In other words, is `self.navigationController `nil`?

Comment: "ok" is printed. please how to know if the self.navigationController nil?

Comment: @rmaddy yes there is view controller before i reach the UIScrollView

Comment: @rmaddy yes the {self.navigationController ==nil}

Comment: Show the code for the nav controller in your app delegate. And for how the current view controller is done.

Comment: @user2670860 Then that is the problem. Your table view controller needs to be in a nav controller for you to be able to push another view controller onto the nav stack.